# Why setting up the revision of a deployment in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

In the book [Kubernetes: Up & Running](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26759355-kubernetes), on the section "Creating Deployments", it has a yaml file that is being used for deployments that starts like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations: 
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
```

What's the point of setting up `deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"`?

This is a file that is going to be applied, not the result of querying the server.

Comment: @CarlosPanato it's not a typo. See my answer to understand why it is necessary.

Comment: makes sense, deleted my comment

Comment: this not an annotation a user is suppose to create, so depending on the context, and since here it's "creating deployments", that's probably a typo.

Answer (score 7):

This annotation is set by Kubernetes. It is required for deployment to identify it's respective Replicaset.

Ok, let me explain. A Deployment creates Replicaset. This Replicaset is responsible for creating Pod's.

Whenever, you made some changes in deployment's podTemplate, it creates a new replicaset. But it don't delete old replicaset as it is necessary if you want to rollback to a previous version.

Now, how deployment will know which replicaset is currently being used? Here comes the `deployment.kubernetes.io/revision:` annotation. Replicaset also contains this annotation. So, deployment know which replicaset is being used by matching revision number of it's annotation with the revision number of replicaset's annotation.

You can read this nice article to understand more: [How Kubernetes Deployments Work](https://thenewstack.io/kubernetes-deployments-work/).

To know how to rollback deploymment to a previous version, see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-back-to-a-previous-revision).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand it. Each time I deploy it creates a replicaset and the deployment keeps track of the replicaset. What's the use of having this in the deplayment.yaml file, it seems to make no difference whether I have it or not.

Comment: @pupeno You are not suppose to set this in `deployment.yaml`. Kubernetes itself will set this.  There might be a copy paste mistake there.

Comment: But that was my question, why is the book Kuberentes: Up & Running includes this in the yaml file.

Answer (score 2):

When I look [inside the book](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Kubernetes_Up_and_Running.html?id=V5qzDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), I see the text you quoted appears as output from the command `kubectl get deployments kuard -- export -o yaml`:

[image: excerpt from book]

So the premise in your question is wrong - it is as a result of querying the server.

Your broader supposition is correct: this is not something you would include in the original source to create a Deployment.